# "Heap use after free" when declared globally, but runs fine when declared locally

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I am solving a question on Leetcode: [Path With Maximum Minimum Value](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-with-maximum-minimum-value/):

> Given an m x n integer matrix grid, return the maximum score of a path starting at (0, 0) and ending at (m - 1, n - 1) moving in the 4 cardinal directions. The score of a path is the minimum value in that path. For example, the score of the path 8 → 4 → 5 → 9 is 4.
> Input: grid = [[5,4,5],[1,2,6],[7,4,6]]
> Output: 4

With some online help, I came up with the code below:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> visited;

    int maximumMinimumPath(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        int m=grid.size(), n=grid[0].size();
       
        visited.resize(m+1,vector<int>(n+1));
        fill(begin(visited),end(visited),vector<int>(n+1,0));

        int l=0, r=min(grid[0][0], grid[m-1][n-1]);
        while(l<r) {
            int m=l+((r-l+1)/2);
            if(pathExists(grid,m)) l=m;
            else r=m-1;
            visited.clear();
        }
        
        return l;
    }
    
    bool pathExists(vector<vector<int>>& grid, int val) {
        queue<pair<int,int>> q;
        visited.clear();
        
        q.push({0,0});
        visited[0][0]=true;
        
        auto qpush = [&](int r, int c){
            if(r<0 || c<0 || r>=grid.size() || c>=grid[0].size() || 
               visited[r][c] || grid[r][c]<val) return;
            visited[r][c]=true;
            q.push({r,c});
        };

        while(q.size()) {
            auto [x,y]=q.front();
            q.pop();
            
            if(x==grid.size()-1 and y==grid[0].size()-1) return true;
            
            qpush(x+1,y);
            qpush(x-1,y);
            qpush(x,y+1);
            qpush(x,y-1);
        }
        
        return false;
    }
};
```

This is throwing me an exception:

> AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x602000000190 at pc 0x000000348250

If I make the `visited` vector local and pass it along to `pathExists()`, the code runs fine and produces the right output.

Why does the current code throw a `heap-use-after-free` exception?  Where is it being used *after* being freed?

Comment: I believe `c>=grid[0].size()` can be evaluated when grid is empty

Comment: Oh, but I am trying it on the sample input in question, @drescherjm.

Comment: How do you think these two lines are going to work `visited.clear(); ... visited[0][0]=true;`? The first line makes `visited` a zero sized vector, the second goes boom.

Comment: `vector::clear` does not zero a vector without changing it's size, it resizes it to zero.

Comment: @john, ah, that helped.  Thanks!  I did not realize `clear()` was resetting its size to 0 - I thought it just cleared (reset) the elements to 0.

Comment: @Someone It seems to be a fairly common misunderstanding.

Comment: @john, if you post this as an answer, I would be glad to accept it.

Comment: @Someone "*I thought [`clear()`] just cleared (reset) the elements to 0*" - Nope. If you want that, you can use [`std::fill()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)/[`std::fill_n()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) instead.